# DI CompositionRoot with multi service WCF Host

Tags: .net, wcf, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

We are developing a selfhosted WCF service host which will be loading services dynamically based on configuration.

I was wondering wether I should consider each service as a mini app and use composition root in each hosted service or use composition root on the service host itself?

Your input is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a composition root per service is fine, but if you can, let your WCF service just contain 1 service with 2 methods: One method that allows you to execute query objects, one method that allows you to execute commands. This way you will still have one Composition Root for your WCF service.

To allow to do this you need to model all mutations as [commands/handlers](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and read operations as [query/handlers](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92). When you've done this, you will never have to change anything to the SVC ever again.

Take a look at the [Silverlight Cookbook](http://silverlightcookbook.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/88277#1732813), which successfully uses this approach. Take a look at the [Main\Cookbook\Services.Host\CommandService.svc.cs](http://silverlightcookbook.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/88277#1732813), which is the entry point of the WCF service.

This will probably turn your world completely upside down, but this architecture is very flexible, scalable, and can lower the maintenance costs dramatically.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. My world has been turned upside down many times over in the past few months, catching up on latest developments in coding. I will definately have a look on Silverlight Cookbok. We are using SimpleInjection DI container which is great work btw!